# How to pass parameters from root html element to ReactJS from Ruby on Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpacker

I am trying to implement **ReactJS** on a **Ruby on Rails application** using [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) gem.

Does anyone know how to read/pass data attributes to ReactJS component.

Please find the code below.
in `index.html.erb`
`<div id="data" data-item-id="<%= @item.id %>"></div>`
in `Data.jsx` file

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

class Data extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

 componentDidMount() {
   this.getSiteDetails();
 }

 getSiteDetails(){
  fetch(i want to pass data attributes here along with the url)
 }

 render() {}
}

ReactDOM.render(<Data />, document.getElementById('data'));
```

Comment: Something like this would work: `let el = document.getElementById('data');
ReactDOM.render(<Data id={el.getAttribute('data-item-id')} />, el);`

Comment: @Brian Thank you very much for the help. I think the following answer is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 getSiteDetails(){
   const itemId = document.getElementById('data').dataset.itemId
   fetch(you can use itemId in here)
 }
```